# NHibernate Query on a Non-Key takes longer time to hydrate objects than query on the single column primary key

Tags: nhibernate, oracle10g

I noticed a peculiar behavior with NHibernate.

Context:
I have a table with a composite key (a number, a string and a date) and a few other columns. I noticed that a query on this table (hibernate class) was significantly slower than queries on other tables. even though there is only one record (hibernate object) returned.

Observation:

1. A surrogate key was introduced and mapped it as the primary key, running the query again resulted in the same performance as before for Object Hydration.
2. Hydration of the object was 6-7 times faster if Queried on the surrogate key. 2.

In all the above query runs, database performance was consistent.

There are no Associations or relationships defined in the hibernate mapping of this table.

I am not able to explain the difference in performance of object hydration (populating the .Net Objects with data).

What can I do to tweak the code to be as performant as the query using the PK when I have to use another column in the criteria.

Thanks in Advance

Kiran

EDIT: Table structure.. I have put in the create table script itself.. as I was not able to format it properly..

CREATE TABLE "TEST" 
  (
     "REFERENCE" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) NOT NULL,
     "PRIORITY" NUMBER(6,0) NOT NULL, 
     "EFF_FROM_DATE" DATE NOT NULL, 
     "EFF_TO_DATE" DATE NOT NULL, 
     "VALUE" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL, 
     "LAST_UPDATE_USERNAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL, 
     "LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME" DATE NOT NULL, 
     "NOTE_1" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
     "NOTE_2" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
  )

Comment: And what database (and which version) are you using?? What do your tables look like (structure, column datatypes) ??

Comment: Oracle 10g. this is a table with the following structureNAME Type NULLABLE
REFERENCE VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) Yes
PRIORITY NUMBER(6,0) Yes
EFF_FROM_DATE DATE Yes
EFF_TO_DATE DATE Yes
VALUE VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) Yes
LAST_UPDATE_USERNAME VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) Yes
LAST_UPDATE_DATE_TIME DATE Yes
NOTE_1 VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) Yes
NOTE_2 VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) Yes                                  What is interesting is that the database queries are very fast.. and takes less than a millisecond.. it is the object hydration time that varies

Comment: please do **not** post table structure into comments -that's **REALLY** hard to read!! Instead: update your original post by **editing it**! Thanks

Comment: how have you implemented GetHashCode()?

Comment: yes we have the Equals and the GetHashCode overridden..

Comment: post mapping of class and class itself please. also it would be nice to have the call that triggers the fetch

Comment: On Profiling, we noticed that the bottleneck is the OracleDataReader.Read. It is much faster when read on a query with PK than on a Query without one..

Comment: One more update: we see similar performance when the query is on the primary key but using a 'in' rather than '='. So I guess it is not a problem with nhibernate. I have gone through the nhibernate code base and verified it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This discrepancy was solved by forcing nhibernate to use the Oracle driver instead of the Microsoft driver for oracle.

I followed steps from this blog
http://www.timvasil.com/blog14/category/Oracle.aspx